# Cannot install Android application on Device Running with ICS 4.0.3

Tags: android, apk

Cannot install Android application on Device Running with ICS 4.0.3.
Description of device

http://www.sinocan.com.cn/index.php?ac=article&at=read&did=204

## Logcat

07-11 04:15:31.963 E/PackageManager(  147): **Package com.sks.myapp requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!**

07-11 04:15:31.963 W/PackageManager(  147): **Package couldn't be installed in /data/app/com.sks.myapp-1.apk**

07-11 04:15:32.043 D/dalvikvm(  147): **GC_EXPLICIT freed 983K, 11% free 10952K/12231K, paused 3ms+14ms**

07-11 04:15:32.043 D/InstallAppProgress( 1648): **Installation error code: -9**

07-11 04:15:33.133 I/InstallAppProgress( 1648): **Finished installing com.sks.myapp**

Comment: is it a device or an emulator?

Comment: Do you have Google Maps installed on the device?

Comment: it is device.
Device details [http://www.sinocan.com.cn/index.php?ac=article&at=read&did=204](http://www.sinocan.com.cn/index.php?ac=article&at=read&did=204)

Comment: Yes Google Maps is installed on device.

Comment: obviously, it is not installed. (or incorrectly)

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks - But Why?. What is wrong with my code.
could you please guide.

Comment: there is probably nothing wrong in your code, simple, the maps library is not available on the device you target. are you sure it is supposed to be there ?

Comment: @njzk2 - Thanks man! Will check with device.